# Rake Aborted! Error while trying to precompile assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, assets, precompile

I'm having some problem on locating image resource so I tried to precompile the assets pipe line. But it is giving me problem. Can anyone please help me on this?

```
$ rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/usr/Rails/app101/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/usr/Rails/app101/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/usr/Rails/app101/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And my `rake assets:precompile --trace` result:

```
$ rake assets:precompile --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/usr/Rails/app101/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/usr/Rails/app101/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/usr/Rails/app101/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:604:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:37:in `<main>
```

Thanks Very Much. :)

Comment: You have the bundler gem installed and have run `bundle install` yes?

Comment: Yaa, I've the bundler gem installed and ran `bundle install`.